# How to get physical address from struct page in linux kernel

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel

Suppose I get a pointer to `struct page` from allocator, how could I get corresponding physical address? Whether does kernel provide functions to achieve it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is page_to_phys(), but please make sure that this is really what you need. e.g., if you want the physical address in order to hand it off to some device for DMA it is very likely what you need is the bus address for the page, which may or may not be the physical address.

http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/asm-generic/page.h#L90

Comment: It is I need if this function is suitable for `ZONE_NORMAL`. Thank you.

Comment: Hello, @gby I reviewed the implementation of `page_to_phys()` is `#define page_to_phys(page)      ((dma_addr_t)page_to_pfn(page) << PAGE_SHIFT)`. It looks like related to DMA. If I hope to get paddr of page allocated to vma of process, is `page_to_phys()` suitable to my case?